# Is there an idiomatic way to keep references to elements of an ever-growing container?

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I'm trying to write a container for objects of type `T` which provides access to references `&T` to the stored objects (I want to avoid making copies). Since the container only ever grows during its lifetime, the lifetime of the returned references `&T` should be the same as for the container.

The closest I got so far was to use `Box<T>` objects internally in my container and use `Box<T>.as_ref()` to return references to these objects. Then, however, I run into the same problem as in this minimal example:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![Box::new(1)]; // line 1
    let x = v[0].as_ref();         // line 2: immutable borrow occurs here
    println!("x = {:?}", x);       // line 3
    v.push(Box::new(2));           // line 4: mutable borrow occurs here -> error
    println!("x = {:?}", x);       // line 5
}
```

I understand that it would be unsound to use `x` in line 5 if it had been deleted from `v` during the the mutable borrow. But that's not the case here, and it'll never be for my container. If there's no safe way to express this in Rust, how could I "repair" the example (without copying `x`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there's nothing "ready to use" for your usecase, but you can write a wrapper around `Vec` that does **unsafe** stuff to give you the features you need while keeping the guarantees that Rust needs

```
struct BoxVec<T>(Vec<Box<T>>);

impl<T> BoxVec<T> {
    pub fn new() -> Self { BoxVec(Vec::new()) }
    pub fn push<'a>(&'a mut self, t: T) -> &'a mut T {
        let mut b = Box::new(t);
        let t: &'a mut T = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<&mut T, &'a mut T>(&mut b) };
        self.0.push(b);
        t
    }
    pub fn pusher<'a>(&'a mut self) -> BoxVecPusher<'a, T> {
        BoxVecPusher(self)
    }
}

struct BoxVecPusher<'a, T: 'a>(&'a mut BoxVec<T>);

impl<'a, T> BoxVecPusher<'a, T> {
    fn push<'b>(&'b mut self, t: T) -> &'a mut T {
        let mut b = Box::new(t);
        let t: &'a mut T = unsafe { std::mem::transmute::<&mut T, &'a mut T>(&mut b) };
        (self.0).0.push(b);
        t
    }
}
```

The guarantees I chose is that you can't index into the `Pusher`, but you get a mutable reference to the newly pushed object. Once to release the pusher, you can go back to indexing.

An example usage is

```
let mut v = BoxVec::new();
v.push(1);
let x = v[0];
let mut p = v.pusher();
let i = p.push(2);
p.push(3); // works now
let y = v[0]; // denied by borrow checker
```

[Full example in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=5499dce382190ba15cb2e3ef4f280950&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Answer (score 5):

As @ker's answer says, just because you only grow a container doesn't mean references stay valid, as the memory can be reallocated.

Another solution if you're only growing the container is to just store indices instead of references:

```
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec!["Foo"];    // line 1
    let x = 0;                  // line 2: just store an index.
    println!("x = {:?}", v[x]); // Use the index as needed
    v.push("bar");              // line 4: No problem, there are no references.
    println!("x = {:?}", v[x]); // line 5: use the index again.
}
```

Comment: Reallocation of Vec's buffer should not be a problem here because the Vec is moving the Box<T>, not the T -- so references to T should remain stable. The index solution is quite suboptimal in my case because identifying the item requires the index plus a reference to the container.

Comment: If you want to stay in safe Rust, though, if you've got a reference to `*v[0]`, you're borrowing `v` too, since otherwise Rust can't catch `v[0] = Box::new("baz")` which would invalidate the reference.  I agree with @ker that `Rc<T>` may be the best answer here.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your `Vec` might run out of memory. If that happens, it has to allocate a new (bigger) chunk of memory, copy all the old data over, and delete the old memory allocation. At that point all references into the old container would become invalid.

You could design a [rope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_%28data_structure%29) (a `Vec` of `Vec`), where, once an inner vec is full, you just create a new one, thus never invalidating pointers just by pushing.

That would require some unsafe code and very careful analysis of the borrowing rules that you have to keep up.

Comment: I'm aware of potential reallocation invalidating the references to the elements of the Vec. That's why I used Vec<Box<T>>: the references to the Box<T> are unstable, but the references to the T are stable, aren't they? After all, Vec<Box<T>> does not require Box<T> to be cloneable, so it can't invalidate the references to the T.

Comment: At that point, what you really want is `Rc<T>`, because that is literally the definition of a shared owned reference in Rust

Comment: The Vec is the (only) owner of the pointer, so reference counting isn't what I want. It is perfectly fine for the references to be invalidated once the lifetime of the owning Vec ends. (I agree reference counting would avoid the whole ownership problem. But I want the references to be as lightweight as possible for performance reasons.)

Comment: Accessing a `T` through an `Rc<T>` is no different from accessing it through a `&T`. Both are represented by a pointer and nothing more. The storage they point to is a little bigger and cloning `Rc`s is heavier, but the access is just a single pointer dereference