# How can I create a Box, put it in a vector and save a mutable reference to it in a struct?

Tags: rust

I'm building a stream-based file parser. The file has the format `$TYPE$CONTENT\n` where `TYPE` is 4 bytes and `content` up to \n.

`$TYPE` is either an attribute of the current record, or indicates that a new record starts. For example:

```
strtPerson
nameMustermann
surnMax
strtPerson
nameMustermann
surnRenate
```

My approach was to open the file, get an iterator over the lines, split the lines and then feed the lines to a parser:

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufRead, BufReader};

pub trait Record {
    fn add_line(&mut self, type_: String, content: String) -> &mut dyn Record;
}

pub struct File {
    pub current_record: Option<Box<dyn Record>>,
    pub records: Vec<Box<dyn Record>>,
}

impl File {
    pub fn push_last_record(&mut self) {
        if self.current_record.is_some() {
            self.records.push(self.current_record.take().unwrap());
        }
    }
}

impl Record for File {
    fn add_line(&mut self, type_: String, content: String) -> &mut dyn Record {
        match &type_[..] {
            "strt" => {
                self.push_last_record();
                self.current_record = Some(Box::new(File {
                    current_record: None,
                    records: Vec::new(),
                }));
            }
            _ => {
                if let Some(current) = &mut self.current_record {
                    current.add_line(type_, content);
                }
            }
        }
        self
    }
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let f =
        "strtPerson\nnameMustermann\nsurnMax\nstrtPerson\nnameMustermann\nsurnRenate".as_bytes();
    let reader = BufReader::new(f);
    let mut f = File {
        current_record: None,
        records: Vec::new(),
    };
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        f.add_line(line[..4].to_owned(), line[5..].to_owned());
    }
    println!("there are {} records read", f.records.len());
    f.push_last_record();
    println!("there are now {} records read", f.records.len());
    Ok(())
}
```

This solution works, but I think it's cumbersome and error prone to require a call to `push_last_record` and I think there could be a more idiomatic solution to this.

My main issue is how to create the new `Record` if the line starts with "start" and somehow save a mutable reference to that so I can directly call the `add_line` function on the latest record.

It boils down to creating a `Box`, putting it in the vector and save a mutable reference to it in the struct.

Is there a ready-made pattern for this or could anyone give me a hint on how to make this clean?

EDIT:

Thanks to the hint with `last_mut()`, I rewrote my code. I'm not sure if it's idiomatic or efficient, but I think it's way cleaner than before.

```
use std::io::{self, BufRead, BufReader};

pub trait Record {
    fn add_line(&mut self, type_: String, content: String) -> &mut dyn Record;
}

pub struct File<'a> {
    pub current_record: Option<&'a mut Box<dyn Record>>,
    pub records: Vec<Box<dyn Record>>,
}

impl Record for File<'_> {
    fn add_line(&mut self, type_: String, content: String) -> &mut dyn Record {
        match &type_[..] {
            "strt" => {
                self.records.push(Box::new(File {
                    current_record: None,
                    records: Vec::new(),
                }));
            }
            _ => {
                if let Some(current) = &mut self.records.last_mut() {
                    current.add_line(type_, content);
                }
            }
        }
        self
    }
}

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let f =
        "strtPerson\nnameMustermann\nsurnMax\nstrtPerson\nnameMustermann\nsurnRenate".as_bytes();
    let reader = BufReader::new(f);
    let mut f = File {
        current_record: None,
        records: Vec::new(),
    };
    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        f.add_line(line[..4].to_owned(), line[5..].to_owned());
    }
    println!("there are {} records read", f.records.len());
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: This code has a lot of typos. `match &code[..]` despite `code` being an `i32`, `&mut den Record` instead of `&mut dyn Record`, missing close braces, a custom `File` struct used in conjuction with the standard library `File` struct, and more. It'd be very helpful if you could put together a [mre].

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Is there an idiomatic way to keep references to elements of an ever-growing container?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41034046/155423); [How can a function append a value to a vector and also return that value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50980100/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for the other questions where if found the last_mut() function of vec. I think that's doing the job.

Answer (score 0):

For the `current_record` you should store the index in the other `Vec` instead of using a temporary reference. Self-referential structs are not safe in Rust, and even if they worked, temporary references in structs are incredibly limiting and impractical to use.

Alternatively, you could use `Arc` instead of `Box` in order to allow one value to live in multiple places.

Comment: Wouldn't be storing an index be somehow the same as using the last_mut()?
The main difference would be, that i store one additional information.
If i'd go for either solutions, it'll mess up if i share it...

Comment: If you can access the right element in some other way than using a temporary reference, that's all fine. If you had a more complex case where indices are not good enough, there's also [generational arena](https://lib.rs/search?q=generational+arena), `Arc`, and [crates that help making self-referential structs](https://lib.rs/crates/ouroboros).